# XML remove node by child node value

Tags: powershell, xpath

I am trying to figure out how to delete a xml node by searching the ModelName or PlatformID based on the XML below. I've tried a few ways but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<HPModels>
  <Model>
    <ModelName>HP EliteBook x360</ModelName>
    <PlatformID>8725</PlatformID>
  </Model>
  <Model>
    <ModelName>HP EliteBook x360</ModelName>
    <PlatformID>876d</PlatformID>
  </Model>
</HPModels>
```

I'm trying to use this but I've had no luck

```
$file = "C:\Temp\test1.xml"
$xmlfile = [XML](Get-Content $file)
$item = Select-XML -Xml $xmlfile -XPath '//ModelName[Name="HP EliteBook x360"]'
$item.Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($item.node)
```

I am getting:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you actually want to delete. I guess you want to remove the whole `<Model>` node in case you find a match?

Comment: Yes, sorry. So I would want to delete the whole <Model> node if a match is found.

<Model>
<ModelName>HP EliteBook x360</ModelName>
<PlatformID>876d</PlatformID>
</Model>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments:

> I would want to delete the whole `<Model>` node if a match is found.

In that case, I would suggest using the following as the base expression`//Model` - then you can use your existing expression as a predicate `[...]`:

```
$items = Select-Xml $xmlFile -XPath '//Model[./ModelName = "HP EliteBook x360"]'
```

Here, we get `Select-Xml` to select all `<Model>` nodes that have an immediate child `<ModelName>`, the inner value of which is `"HP EliteBook x360"`

You can also use the `..` selector to "walk back up" to the parent node after resolving the appropriate child node:

```
$items = Select-Xml $xmlFile -XPath '//ModelName[. = "HP EliteBook x360"]/..'
```

I (personally) don't like this pattern, but it *is* perfectly valid XPath :)

---

Once the selector expression is fixed, make sure you process the results 1 at a time - `Select-Xml` might return multiple nodes:

```
foreach($item in $items){
    $node = $item.Node
    $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
}
```

---

If you want to accept different model names as parameter arguments, add a `param()` block on the first line of the script and then use that in the XPath expression:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$FilePath,

  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [string]$ModelName
)

if($ModelName -like "*'*"){
  throw 'Cannot process model name with apostrophe'
  return
}

$file = Convert-Path $FilePath
$xmlfile = [XML](Get-Content $file)
$items = Select-XML -Xml $xmlfile -XPath "//ModelName[Name='${ModelName}']"

foreach($item in $items){
  $node = $item.Node
  $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
}

$xmlfile.Save($file)
```

Then pass the parameter arguments for the file path and model name when calling the script:

```
.\Remove-ModelFromXml.ps1 -FilePath .\path\to\file.xml -ModelName "HP EliteBook x360"
```

Comment: Thank you. Now when I run it comes back that it found it but it doesn't delete it for some reason.

ModelName                PlatformID
---------                ----------
HP EliteBook x360 8725

Comment: @AntPro Are you using PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: I'm using PS 5.1.22000.282

Comment: @AntPro Then I'm afraid I have no good explanation :) How are you testing whether it's been removed or not?

Comment: :). I'm just looking in the XML file and the entry still exists.

Comment: @AntPro you need to write `$xmlFile` back to disk after removal in order to persist it, the file won't magically update on its own: `$xmlFile.Save($file)`

Comment: that worked like a charm. I assumed it would automatically remove it but I was wrong. THANK YOU!

Comment: How could I add a variable for the model name?

Comment: @AntPro Change the expression to `"//${tagToRemove}[./${childNodeName} = '${childValue}']"` and assign `$tagToRemove = 'Model';$childNodeName = 'ModelName'; $childValue = 'HP EliteBook x360'` before calling `Select-Xml`

Comment: @AntPro If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark outline on the left :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to do $modelname = "HP whatever on the top of the script"

$tagToRemove = 'Model';$childNodeName = 'ModelName'; $childValue = "$modelname"

Comment: @AntPro I've added an example of how to parameterize the script. If you have any further questions, feel free to [ask another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen. This is the correct way to do it if anyone else wants to know.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<HPModels>
  <Model>
    <ModelName>HP EliteBook x360</ModelName>
    <PlatformID>8725</PlatformID>
  </Model>
  <Model>
    <ModelName>HP EliteBook x360 1030</ModelName>
    <PlatformID>876d</PlatformID>
  </Model>
</HPModels>
```

```
$modelselect = "HP EliteBook x360"

$file = "C:\Temp\test1.xml"
$xmlfile = [XML](Get-Content $file)
$item = Select-Xml $xmlFile -XPath "//Model[./ModelName = '$modelselect']"

foreach($node in $item.Node)
{
$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
}

$xmlFile.Save($file)
```

Comment: Note that the proper way to load XML is: `$xmlfile = [xml]::new(); $xmlfile.Load($file)`. The `Get-Content` method ignores the _encoding_ attribute of the XML file. If it works, then only by pure luck.

Comment: @zett42. It definitely works with Get-Content. I will try your way tomorrow AM. Thanks!

Comment: @zett42 this works well and is faster. I will use this going forward. Thank you!