# XML Xpath with variable to remove node

Tags: powershell

Thanks to the help of @Mathias R. Jessen i was able to get this working but what I am trying to do is add a variable on the top of the script to set the model name but i am not having any luck. Any ideas?

```
$modelselect = "HP EliteBook x360 830 G7"

$file = "C:\Temp\test1.xml"
$xmlfile = [XML](Get-Content $file)
$item = Select-Xml $xmlFile -XPath '//Model[./ModelName = "$modelselect"]'

foreach($node in $item.Node)
{
$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
}

$xmlFile.Save($file)
```

Comment: The outer single quotes on the expression `'//Model[./ModelName = "$modelselect"]'` are not allowing the variable expansion. `"//Model[./ModelName = '$modelselect']"` should work.

Comment: Did you see the [last update to the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70714039/712649)? Notice I swapped `'` and `"` in the string literal to allow expansion of `$ModelName`

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Sorry, I didn't. I will go check. Thank you, appreciate all your help! First time working with XML.

Comment: In short: Only `"..."` strings (double-quoted, called _expandable strings_) perform string interpolation (expansion of variable values) in PowerShell, not `'...'` strings (single-quoted, called _verbatim strings_): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's _expandable strings_ and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of PowerShell _string literals in general_.

Answer (score 1):

The below worked, thank you, everyone!

```
"//Model[./ModelName = '$modelselect']"
```